# Sending alert dialog entry to mysql database

Tags: java, android

Am new to android and i have successfully manged to show data from mysql database in a list and set an alert dialog for when an item is clicked.The Alert dialog has to take in a comment about the item clicked and send it to the mysql database but am stuck at making the connection.
Here is my code

```
 public void showList(){
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
        peoples = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS);

        for(int i=0;i<peoples.length();i++){
            JSONObject c = peoples.getJSONObject(i);
            String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
            String fname = c.getString(TAG_FNAME);
            String lname = c.getString(TAG_LNAME);
            String idnum = c.getString(TAG_IDNUM);

            HashMap<String,String> persons = new HashMap<String,String>();

            persons.put(TAG_ID,id);
            persons.put(TAG_FNAME,fname);
            persons.put(TAG_LNAME,lname);
            persons.put(TAG_IDNUM,idnum);

            personList.add(persons);
        }

        final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                SearchActivity.this, personList, R.layout.list_activity,
                new String[]{TAG_ID,TAG_FNAME,TAG_LNAME,TAG_IDNUM},
                new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.textViewFname, R.id.textViewLname,R.id.textViewIdnum}
        );

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        //alert dialog
        //Create onclick listener class
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                /* Alert Dialog Code Start*/
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                alert.setTitle("Alert id: "+TAG_IDNUM); //Set Alert dialog title here
                alert.setMessage("Enter Your Comment here"); //Message here

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // convert the input to a string and show in a toast.
                        String srt = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Commenting Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } // End of onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                }); //End of alert.setPositiveButton
                alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Commenting cancled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
   /* Alert Dialog Code End*/
                // End of onClick(View v)


            }




        });}
catch (JSONException e){}
}
```

Comment: The same way you get data from the server, its the same way you send it. You can either POST or add the data to the URL. The Only difference is that because you are not expecting any data back the only thing you will be interested in is a SUCCESS callback. So upon click on the Dialog get the TEXT and send it using the same method you GET data from the SERVER  using either one of the 2 methods i mentioned above. POST is more secure than adding data to the URL

Answer (score 0):

So i managed to come up with the following but the variables am sending to the php file don't seem to be getting there.

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                /* Alert Dialog Code Start*/
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

                final String id_number =((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewIdnum)).getText().toString();

                alert.setTitle("Alert id: "+id_number); //Set Alert dialog title here
                alert.setMessage("Enter Your Comment here"); //Message here

                // Set an EditText view to get user input
                final EditText input = new EditText(context);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // convert the input to a string and show in a toast.
                        String reason = input.getEditableText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Commenting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        final String reason_key = input.getText().toString().trim();
                        //final String id_number_key = textview;

                        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.RESULT_URL,

                                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                },
                                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                });
                        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        params.put(TAG_IDNUM,id_number);
                        params.put(reason_key,reason);

                        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SearchActivity.this);
                        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

                    } // End of onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                }); //End of alert.setPositiveButton
                alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        // Canceled.
                        Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this,"Commenting cancled",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }); //End of alert.setNegativeButton
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
   /* Alert Dialog Code End*/
                // End of onClick(View v)


            }




        });}
catch (JSONException e){}
}
```